# Closedness of $Q^3=\{(x,t)\in\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}:\|x\|_2\leq t\}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

Let the set $Q^3=\{(x,t)\in\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}:\|x\|_2\leq t\}$.

In my math notes, it is written that the proof of the closedness of $Q^3$ "follows from continuity of the $\ell_2$ norm." Can someone explain the connection between the norm and the set being closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that norm is a continuous map, the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&(x,t)&\mapsto&\lVert x\rVert_2-t\end{array}$$is continuous. And $Q^3=f^{-1}\bigl((-\infty,0]\bigr)$. So, since $(-\infty,0]$ is closed, $Q^3$ is closed too.

Comment: So it is true that the continuous mapping of a closed set is a closed set? It makes sense intuitively. Thanks!

Comment: No! The *reverse image* of a closed set by a continuous map is a closed set.

Comment: But we are applying $f$ to $Q^3$ and getting a closed set. Are there other $f'$ such that we would get an open set? Sorry, I have no background in real analysis!

Comment: I don't understand your question. I got $Q^3$ as the reverse image of $(-\infty,0]$ with respect to the continuous map $f$. Therefore, $Q^3$ is closed. That's all.

Comment: Never mind, I looked it up and got a sufficient answer